# How to get the max width of my css element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the `max width` of my CSS element by `using javascript`.
I'm currently able to get the `width but not max-width`.

`hsWidth = $("#horizontal-scroll").width();`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery method **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** :

```
var max_width = $("#horizontal-scroll").css('max-width');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var max_width = $("#horizontal-scroll").css('max-width');

console.log(max_width);
```

```css
#horizontal-scroll{
  max-width: 250px; 
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="horizontal-scroll"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `css('max-width')`

The following should do it for you

```
$('#horizontal-scroll').css('max-width');
```

You can find more information [here in the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Also, please note as per the comment by @low_rents that this will
>   return a string with the measurement unit at the end, for example
>   '100px' or '50%'

Comment: but be aware that this will return a `string` with the measurement unit at the end, for example `'100px'` or `'50%'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `'.css()'` method :

```
$('#horizontal-scroll').css('maxWidth');
```

[Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this working example

```js
//referencing your example..
 var hsWidth = $("#horizontal-scroll").css('max-width');
 console.log(hsWidth);
```

```css
#horizontal-scroll{
  height:500px;
  width:auto;
  max-width:950px;/*we want to get this...*/
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--target element-->
<div id="horizontal-scroll">
</div>
```